# Coloured Boxplot

Tags: r, boxplot

I have a matrix of 12 columns, and I am using `boxplot` function in `R` to plot the boxplot.

following commands are used:

```
pdf("data.pdf") 
data<-read.table("data1", header=T) 
boxplot(data, outline=F)
dev.off()
```

What I want, is to present the first three boxplots in red, green, and blue. while the next three  in yellow, next three  in orange and next three in purple.

How can I do this?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get colours, you just need to pass a vector of colours to the boxplot function:

```
##Create some dummy data
runif(10*12), ncol=12)
##Create a vector of 12 colours
cols = rep(c("yellow", "orange", "purple"), each=3)
cols = col=c("red", "green","blue",cols)

##Plot as normal
boxplot(dd, col=cols)
```

---

BTW, don't load your data at every iteration of your for loop. Load it once:

```
data <- read.table("data1", header=T) 
pdf("data.pdf") 
boxplot(data, outline=F)
dev.off()
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, one more thing how can I rotate my x axis label by 45 degrees?

Comment: See the [documentation](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/FAQ/R-FAQ.html#How-can-I-create-rotated-axis-labels_003f)

Comment: Where did you get `angle=45` from?